# Function satisfing : $h(x)=f(2x-1)$ with $f'(-1)=0 $ and $f'(2)=-2$ then what is $h'(x) $?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, education

I find in some book this function defined as follow $h(x)=f(2x-1)$ .

with $f'(2)=-2 $ and $f'(-1)=0$ , we would like to know $h'(3/2)$ ?

In the  book take $h'(x)=f'(2x-1)=(f'(2))x+f'(-1)=-2x $

but i know $f(2x-1)$ is a composition of two function ,why they didn't  take

$h'(x)=2f'(2x-1)$ ?

Thank you for any help !!!

Comment: Your reasoning is right, except for the fact that you somehow tacitly transformed $2x+1$ to $2x-1$ along the way.

Comment: can you give us the name of book?

Comment: it is arabic book for 3AS MATH

Comment: i think it is wrong but how i can show to my student ?

Comment: http://www.eddirasa.com/activite-1-page-40-partie1/

Comment: @IvanNeretin, sorry it is typo , h(x)=f(2x-1) not f(2x+1) i edited it

Comment: @zeraouliarafik,I also saw one such example in multivariable calculus.I also don't know the exact reason behind it but I think it's probably because $f^{'}$ is linear transformation(may be).

Comment: As @IvanNeretin said, your reasoning is right. What's wrong with the explanation "This is a composition of two functions, you need to use the chain rule" and possibly explain the origin of the chain rule if necessary? If you want to provide a counterexample you could use $f(x)=-\frac{1}{3}(x+1)^2$ where $f'(x)=-\frac{2}{3}(x+1)$ and $h(x)=-\frac{4}{3}x^2$. Then compare $f'(2x-1)=-\frac{4}{3}x$ and $2f'(2x-1)=-\frac{8}{3}x$ with $h'(x)=-\frac{8}{3}x$ and there'll be no doubt which one is wrong.